# Test the convergence of: $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

#### My Solution

> Let the subscript begin at 1. Group the terms three by three. The partial sum $S_{n}$ satisfies
>
> $$S_{3n}-S_{3(n-1)}=\frac{1}{3n-2}+\frac{1}{3n-1}-\frac{1}{3n} > \frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n}-\frac{1}{3n}=\frac{1}{3n},\quad(n\ge1),$$
>
> where $S_0=0$. Thus $S_{3n}>\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3i}$ and $S_{3n}$ diverges as $n\to+\infty$. As $\{S_{3n}\}$ is a divergent *subseries (?)* of $\{S_n\}$, so the original series must be divergent.

#### Questions

1. Is the word "subseries" correct? [**Edit**: Yeah, I find "subsequence" a better word.]
2. Is my solution a rigorous proof? [**Edit**: It is a proof. It has no flaw. It is rigorous.]
3. Are there other different / elegant / interesting solutions? [**Edit:** Seems that my solution is succinct enough.]
4. What is a [*rigorous* proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigorous_proof#Mathematical_rigour)? [**Edit**: A proof that has no flaw is rigorous.]

Thank you all!

Comment: I think "subseries" is fine in this context since there isn't really a chance of confusion. If you really want to be formal, I would define the sequence of partial sums $(S_n)$ and then just call $(S_{3n})$ a subsequence of $(S_n)$.

Comment: Thank you. Can someone show me how I can apply Cauchy's convergence test? I don't know how to combine the three different cases of $n \mod 3 = 0,1,2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think subseries is a fine word, saying exactly what you want.  I would accept your solution-especially as it is the one I would offer.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind sparing some time for the Cauchy's test? My classmate says that Cauchy's can do the trick too, but I dare not go beyond the definition.

Comment: What you have done shows that Cauchy's test will not prove convergence.  If I give you $\epsilon$ you can show that adding enough terms far out will exceed that.  It is the same proof as the harmonic series, with a factor $3$ that you have identified.